# issues of installing mujoco and baseline library

Tags: python

according the following paragraph [Vectorized Environment](https://blog.paperspace.com/getting-started-with-openai-gym/#:%7E:text=FIRE%27%2C%20%27RIGHT%27%2C%20%27LEFT%27%5D-,Vectorized%20Environments,-A%20lot%20of),

i wanted to install library  baselines, first time it  told me that i should install mujoco, i have searched across internet information about this library and found that  i could install it using following command
pip install free-mujoco-py
but i got following errors :

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source 
of the following dependency conflicts.
yellowbrick 1.3.post1 requires numpy<1.20,>=1.16.0, but you have numpy 1.22.1 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.6.0 requires numpy~=1.19.2, but you have numpy 1.22.1 which is incompatible.
```

actually mujoco-py is installed i can  call it using

```
import mujoco_py
```

but when i have tried

```
 pip install baselines
```

i got :

```
Building wheel for mujoco-py (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys
.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gibatj1_\\mujoco-py_ec86452e9e9f4ec2b2c6293e0dac635a\\setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-gibatj1_\\mujoco-py_ec86452e9e9f4ec2b2c6293e0dac635a\\setup.py'"'"';f =
 getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup
()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d '
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-f0q_yw3t'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gibatj1_\mujoco-py_ec86452e9e9f4ec2b2c6293e0dac635a\
  Complete output (54 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build

  You appear to be missing MuJoCo.  We expected to find the file here: C:\Users\User\.mujoco\mjpro150

  This package only provides python bindings, the library must be installed separately.
```

what happens? please help me

Comment: you need to install mjpro150. download it here https://www.roboti.us/download/mjpro150_win64.zip. place it and the key in %userprofile%\.mujoco. and Powershell set path variable $env:PATH += ";C:\Users\*\.mujoco\mjpro150\bin". follow this. https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/issues/253#issuecomment-446025520

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem is about the version of numpy

```
pip install numpy==1.19.2
```

Can solve your problem about your installation problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).